# Neutron pair annihilation cross-section

Tags: quantum-chromodynamics, scattering-cross-section

I'm having a surprisingly difficult time finding this information. My expectation is that the total pair annihilation cross-section is something like $\langle\sigma v\rangle_{n\bar n}\sim \Lambda_{\rm QCD}^{-2}$ at $s\sim \Lambda_{\rm QCD}^2\sim (200 {\rm MeV})^2$. However, I care about order 1 factors, so if anyone has a good reference on hand, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Not surprising., a pair of neutrons cannot annihilate , it would violate baryon number conservation. Did you mean a pair of neutrino antineutrino?  example https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.02017

Comment: @ anna v OP meant neutron antineutron